# Centering Values on Bars in Histogram in R

Tags: r

Looking to have the values of x-axis plotted in the center of the bars in R.

Having issues finding a way to make this possible, code is below:

```
hist(sample_avg, breaks =7, ylim=c(0,2000), 
    main = 'Histogram of Sample Average for 1 Coin Flip', xlab= 'Sample Average')
```

This is just for a coin flip, so I have 6 possible values and want to have 6 buckets with the x-axis tick marks underneath each respective bar.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You might consider using `barplot` instead when dealing with discrete outcomes. The default barplot also centers the x-axis labels under the bars.

Answer (score 13):

`hist()` returns the x coordinate of the midpoints of the bars in the `mids` components, so you can do this:

```
sample_avg <- sample(size=10000,x=seq(1,6),replace=TRUE)
foo <- hist(sample_avg, breaks =7, ylim=c(0,2000), 
    main = 'Histogram of Sample Average for 1 Coin Flip', xlab= 'Sample Average',
    xaxt="n")
axis(side=1,at=foo$mids,labels=seq(1,5))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
# when dealing with histogram of integers, 
# then adding some residual ~ 0.001 will fix it all...
# example:
v = c(-3,5,5,4,10,8,8)
a = min(v)
b = max(v)
foo = hist(v+0.001,breaks=b-a,xaxt="n",col="orange",
panel.first=grid(),main="Histogram of v",xlab="v")
axis(side=1,at=foo$mids,labels=seq(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as nifty as you might have been hoping, but looks like the best thing is to use axes=F, then put in your own axes with the 'axis' command, specifying the tick marks you want to see.

Reference: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-June/164271.html

Comment: Tried that, but the last value is getting cut off everytime I do that. Do you know of any way to get around that? I tried messing with the length but keep getting that my 'at' and 'labels' are differing by 1.

Comment: Nevermind, got it figured out using $mids. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: You may get better results by specifying the breakpoints directly, using `breaks=seq(0.5,6.5)` instead of `breaks=7`.