# R Histograms X axis not equal distributed

Tags: r, histogram

I woould like to display a histogram with the allocation of school notes.

The dataframe looks like:

```
> print(xls)
# A tibble: 103 x 2
    X__1 X__2 
   <dbl> <chr>
 1     3 w    
 2     1 m    
 3     2 m    
 4     1 m    
 5     1 w    
 6     0 m    
 7     3 m    
 8     1 w    
 9     0 m    
10     5 m
```

I create the histogram with:

```
hist(xls$X__1, main='Notenverteilung', xlab='Note (0 = keine Beurteilung)', ylab='Anzahl')
```

It looks like:
[image]
Why are there spaces between 1,2,3 but not between 0 & 1?

Thanks, BR Bernd

Comment: the left bar is showing the number of `0`'s and the right the count of `1`'s. This looks pretty ok for me. In your case you can try `barplot(table(xls$X__1))` perhaps or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461837/centering-values-on-bars-in-histogram-in-r) e.g. `foo <- hist(xls$X__1, xaxt = "n", breaks = seq(min(xls$X__1),max(xls$X__1)));
axis(side=1,at=foo$mids,labels=seq(min(xls$X__1),max(xls$X__1))[-1])`

Comment: Thanks, a simple barplot did it!

Answer (score 2):

Use `ggplot2` for that, and your bars will be aligned

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(xls, aes(x = X__1)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: What's about  `geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)`? Aligned is not the correct phrase here.

Comment: not aligned... gap between 1 and 2 > gap between 2 and 3

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
barplot(table(xls$X__1))
```

[image]

or try

```
h <- hist(xls$X__1, xaxt = "n", breaks = seq(min(xls$X__1), max(xls$X__1)))
axis(side=1, at=h$mids, labels=seq(min(xls$X__1), max(xls$X__1))[-1])
```

[image]

and using ggplot

```
ggplot(xls, aes(X__1)) + 
   geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, color=2) +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(xls$X__1), max(xls$X__1)))
```

[image]